# Flutter Navigator Pop does not work

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have found flutter yesterday and have tried around a bit, though I have one problem. I have followed a tutorial to implement a Navigation Drawer ([this one](https://medium.com/@kashifmin/flutter-setting-up-a-navigation-drawer-with-multiple-fragments-widgets-1914fda3c8a8)) and the drawer opens nice and all and the buttons change what they should change BUT the call to Navigator.pop(context) or Navigator.of(context).pop() (both) behaves like this:

Before tap on "Characters"

[image: Before tap]

After tap on "Characters"

[image: After tap]

I have searched around the web but I couldn't find anyone with the same issue :/ Here's my code:

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dnd/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'DnD',
        home: new Home()
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dnd/home_fragment.dart';
import 'package:dnd/char_fragment.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int selectedDrawerIndex = 0;

  getDrawerItemWidget(int pos) {
    switch(pos) {
      case 0:
        return new HomeFragment();
      case 1:
        return new CharFragment();

      default:
        return new Text('ERROR');
    }
  }

  onSelectItem(int index) {
    setState(() => selectedDrawerIndex = index);
    print(Navigator.of(context).pop());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'DnD',
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(
            'DnD'
          )
        ),
        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: new Text(
                  'bla'
                ),
                accountEmail: null,
              ),
              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(
                      'Home'
                    ),
                    leading: new Icon(
                      Icons.home
                    ),
                    selected: 0 == selectedDrawerIndex,
                    onTap: () => onSelectItem(0),
                  ),
                  new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(
                      'Characters'
                    ),
                    leading: new Icon(
                      Icons.person
                    ),
                    selected: 1 == selectedDrawerIndex,
                    onTap: () => onSelectItem(1),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: getDrawerItemWidget(selectedDrawerIndex)
      )
    );
  }
}
```

home_fragment.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeFragment extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new Text(
        'moin'
      )
    );
  }
}
```

char_fragment.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CharFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
      return new CharState();
    }
}

class CharState extends State<CharFragment> {
  characterNew() async {
    await showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      child: new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Create new Character?'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text('Yes'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true)
          ),
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text('No'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false)
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        children: <Widget>[
          new RaisedButton.icon(
            onPressed: characterNew,
            icon: new Icon(Icons.add, size: 80.0,),
            label: new Text('')
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the home.dart Build override. Try to return a Scaffold instead of another instance of Material app. You now return a Material app in the body of the material app. You should return just the Scaffold there.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just blindly copy-pasted from the main.dart xD that fixed it!

Answer (score 14):

There are two things that are wrong in your code:

1. You are using `MaterialApp` twice, you should only have one instance of `MaterialApp` as it holds your root configuration.
2. You are not pushing any route on the `Navigator` stack, so you are trying to `pop` from an empty list (ie, there is nothing inside the stack to be popped).

To demonstrate, you are controlling the content of the `Scaffold` body by using `setState` so you are switching between `Home` and `Charaters` widgets and they really can not see each other (if you choose `Home` widget, your `Char` widget is not built, now if you choose your `Char` widget, your `Home` widget has been fully replaced by it)

Comment: Not 100% sure where you're wrong in your second point. But opening a drawer in a Scaffold does give you the ability to close it with pop. Even with a empty Navigator stack. Maybe the opening of a drawer fills the Navigator stack? Like i said. Not 100% sure :)

Comment: hmmm, I did not totally mean that "you have to push to pop". What is really confusing is that the part where replacing the `body` content using `setState` it should not allow you to reverse `state` on `pop`.

Comment: @aziza and @KevinWalter this is from doc: `When a user opens the Drawer, Flutter will add the drawer to the navigation stack under the hood. Therefore, to close the drawer, we can call Navigator.pop(context).`

Comment: Right, if you use `pushReplacement`, then there is nothing in the Navigator stack to `pop`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is this

`onTap: () { Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(); },`